# What is the difference between ConversationState and UserState?

Tags: botframework

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core) does not talk about differences or use cases so I am confused as to when either one should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bot Framework makes use of three types of state for managing how information is stored and retrieved. The three types are user state, conversation state, and private conversation state (each a subclass of *bot state*) with each serving a slightly different purpose depending on how and when the user interacts with the bot.

As you can read from the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#state-management),

- User state is available in any turn that the bot is conversing with that user on that channel, regardless of the conversation
- Conversation state is available in any turn in a specific conversation, regardless of user (i.e. group conversations)
- Private conversation state is scoped to both the specific conversation and to that specific user.

Hope of help!!

Answer (score 0):

Conversation State used when a new conversation restarts then clear the conversation data. 
For Example, if you used emulator then make one demo then 2 states create: 
**i) Conversation State countConversationState** ii) **User State countUserState.**

Both State HOLD Count Of Message. Programmatically you can try a demo of the count when you send a message to the bot.

When you click on Conversation Restart  [image]

after the conversation restart, **Conversation State Count will be 0** and **user state count will be old**.

So Point is that is when your conversation restarts then the user state not clear.
User State useful when user-related information  OR Static Information which identifies the user. Some information no need to change when the conversation restart.